# Freely Moving Cloth Clip on a String

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, string

A cloth clip is kept on a rope such that it can move freely along the rope. The rope is slack, (but tied at two end such that the clip cannot escape), is rotated at a high speed for a substantial time until the system does not tend to change (is at equilibrium). It is seen that whatever may be the length of the rope the clip moves to the center of the rope after rotation (irrespective of the initial conditions). Why does this happen and, if possible explain mathematically?

Comment: I'm thinking this would be true only if the two ends of the rope are at the same height (like a jump rope).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we are assuming the traditional 'frictionless rope' then

The rotated body (The clip) requires a centripetal force to move it in the circular path.
Since there is no friction, it will tend to move in a straight line until the tension in the rope restrains it. It will move in the largest circle possible, since there is NO centripetal force until the rope becomes taut. The rope becomes taut (and the maximum radius exists) when both sides are the same length, i.e. when the body is in the centre.

If you allow friction then I think you can establish that it will NOT reach the centre until the required centripetal force at given angular velocity is greater than the frictional force between rope and body...